# How to draw a line plot in ggplot using a data.frame file?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, line-plot

Thank you for reading. I find that I am unable to draw line plot from my existing data as below:

```
a=structure(list(ID = structure(1:3, .Names = c("V2", "V3", "V4"
), .Label = c(" day1", " day2", " day3"), class = "factor"), 
    Protein1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Names = c("V2", 
    "V3", "V4"), .Label = c("-0.651129553", "-1.613977035", "-1.915631511"
    ), class = "factor"), Protein2 = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 2L), .Names = c("V2", "V3", "V4"), .Label = c("-1.438858662", 
    "-2.16361761", "-2.427593862"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Protein1", "Protein2"), row.names = c("V2", 
"V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame")
```

What I need is to draw a graph as below:

[image]

I have tried the following codes but the results are not ok;

```
qplot(ID, Protein1, data=a, colour=ID, geom="line")
```

Also:

```
a1<-melt(a, id.vars="ID")
ggplot(a1,aes(ID,value))+ geom_line()+geom_point()
```

So many thanks for your care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to modify the structure of your data.frame : `Protein1` & `Protein2` should be numeric and not factors.

```
a$Protein1 = as.numeric(as.character(a$Protein1))
a$Protein2 = as.numeric(as.character(a$Protein2))
```

If you only want to plot "Protein1", you do not need to use melt first.

```
ggplot(a, aes(x = ID, y = Protein1)) 
  + geom_point() 
  + geom_line(aes(group = 1)) 
  + ylim(-3,3)
```

`group = 1` permits connecting points with `geom_line()` : [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082601/ggplot2-line-chart-gives-geom-path-each-group-consist-of-only-one-observation)

---

Now, if you want to see `Protein1` & `Protein2` on the same plot, you can use `melt` :

```
a1<-melt(a, id.vars="ID")
ggplot(a1, aes(x = ID, y = value, group = variable, color = variable)) 
  + geom_point() 
  + geom_line() 
  + ylim(-3,3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please help me to add the legends on the lines within the plot?

Comment: If you only want to move the legend (bottom, right), use : 
    `+ theme(legend.justification=c(1,0), legend.position=c(1,0))`

If you want to only write the labels :
    `+ geom_text(data = a1[a1$ID == " day3",], aes(label = variable), vjust = -1, hjust = 0)`.

Be careful, I saw that the levels of ID are " day1", with a blank character.

Comment: perfect. Thank you. Just one more point. Do you know how is it possible to add a label per line instead of a label per point? one "Protein1" word for red line and one "Protein2" word for blue one.

Comment: You have to explicit the subset of the date, with only one point (for example " day3", or " day1", ...) for each "protein":
`geom_text(data = a1[a1$ID == " day3",], aes(label = variable), vjust = -1, hjust = 0)`