# R ggplot2: Line overlayed on Bar Graph (from separate data frames)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar graph coming from one set of monthly data and I want to overlay on it data from another set of monthly data in the form of a line.  Here is a simplified example (in my data the second data set is not a simple manipulation of the first):

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

test<-abs(rnorm(12)*1000)
test<-rbind(test, test+500)
colnames(test)<-month.abb[seq(1:12)]
rownames(test)<-c("first", "second")
otherTest<-apply(test, 2, mean)
test<-melt(test)
otherTest<-as.data.frame(otherTest)

p<-ggplot(test, aes(x=Var2, y=value,  fill=Var1, order=-as.numeric(Var2))) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
    ggtitle("Test Graph") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(rgb(1,1,1), rgb(.9,0,0))) + 
    guides(fill=FALSE) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

works great to get the bar graph:
[image]

but I have tried multiple iterations to get the line on there and can't figure it out (like this):

```
p + geom_line(data=otherTest,size=1, color=rgb(0,.5,0)
```

Also, if anybody knows how I can make the bars in front of each other so that all you see is a red bar of height 500, I would appreciate any suggestions.  I know I can just take the difference between the two lines of the matrix and keep it as a stacked bar but I thought there might be an easy way to put both bars on the x-axis, white in front of red.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems to deal with here.

Directly answering your question, if you don't provide a `mapping` via `aes(...)` in a geom call (like your `geom_line...`), then the mapping will come from `ggplot()`. Your `ggplot()` specifies `x=Var2, y=value,  fill=Var1...`. All of these variable names must exist in your data frame `otherTest` for this to work, and they don't right now.

So, you either need to ensure that these variable names exist in `otherTest`, or specify `mapping` separately in `geom_line`. You might want to read up about how these layering options work. E.g., [here's a post of mine](https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/mean-and-ci-plot-for-twoway-designs-using-ggplot2) that goes into some detail.

If you go for the first option, some other problems to think about:

- is `Var2` a factor with the same levels in both data frames? It probably should be.
- to use `geom_line` as you are, you might need to add `group = 1`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082601/ggplot2-line-chart-gives-geom-path-each-group-consist-of-only-one-observation).

Some others too, but here's a brief example of what you might do:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

test <- abs(rnorm(12)*1000)
test <- rbind(test, test+500)
colnames(test) <- month.abb[seq(1:12)]
rownames(test) <- c("first", "second")
otherTest <- apply(test, 2, mean)
test <- melt(test)

otherTest <- data.frame(
  Var2 = names(otherTest),
  value = otherTest
)

otherTest$Var2 = factor(otherTest$Var2, levels = levels(test$Var2))

ggplot(test, aes(x = Var2, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Var1), stat="identity") +
  geom_line(data = otherTest)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!  why do you need the line that factors Var2?  I took it out and it still seems to work fine.  Also, any thoughts on how to get the bars one in front of the other instead of stacked?

Comment: I use factors to be certain of the order. Using strings will create the order for you (which I prefer to avoid). Re bars in front of each, you might try adding `position="identity"`