# R - geom_line() transforming points to vertical lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am melting a data frame in order to plot it in ggplot2. However,
`geom_line()` is not giving me horizontal lines. Instead it is transforming my points to vertical lines. I will attach images and add the code to further illustrate:

Using only `geom_point()`:

```
vecmmelt = melt(tail(tempdf,7), id.vars = "Date")

ggplot(vecmmelt, aes(x = Date, y = value, colour = variable, group=1)) +geom_point()+theme_bw()
```

[image: Using geom point only]

Now I would expect to have the following when using `geom_line()`:

[image: Expectation from + geom_line]

What I am really getting by using the following code is the following picture:

```
vecmmelt = melt(tail(tempdf,7), id.vars = "Date")

ggplot(vecmmelt, aes(x = Date, y = value, colour = variable, group=1)) +geom_point()+geom_line()
```

[image: Reality that is wrong]

I tried using `geom_path()` and it also is wrong

Comment: Can you give us a `dput` so we can see your data? [Reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try changing the group aesthetic to `group = variable`

Comment: You are right but see my answer because I have another question now :) about your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you are specifying `group=1`, which tells ggplot to connect all the dots. As [Mario Barbé](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29019102/2254210) explained for a similar question:

> For line graphs, the data points must be grouped so that it knows which points to connect. In this case, it is simple -- all points should be connected, so group=1. When more variables are used and multiple lines are drawn, the grouping for lines is usually done by variable.

Reference: [Cookbook for R, Chapter: Graphs Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2), Line graphs.](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/)

So, in your case, you should specify `group=variable` to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not because of your variable grouping, but because your date format is not correct. Instead of it understanding it as d-M-Y, it is understanding it as M-d-Y, so you have many values for each months but not days in between. Try reformating your date:
`df$Date <-as.Date(paste(df$Year, df$Momnth, 01), "%Y %m %d")`