# ggplot - geom_line not plotting line

Tags: r, ggplot2

with a dataframe `df` like below, Im trying to create a line chart for one of the parameters - `Income` - in the real data there are other parameters.

```
text <- "
Parameter,Company, Qtr, Value
Income, Comp1, Q1FY18, 100
Income, Comp1, Q2FY18, 110
Income, Comp1, Q3FY18, 130
Income, Comp2, Q1FY18, 60
Income, Comp2, Q2FY18, 70
Income, Comp2, Q3FY18, 90
"
df <- read.table(textConnection(text), sep=",", header = T,
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I created a function such that I can re-use this - the function takes a dataframe and set of metrics and plot them

```
plotMetricsLine <- function(df, metrics) {
  df <- df %>%
    filter(Parameter %in% metrics)
  p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Qtr, y=Value,color = Company)) +
    geom_line(size=1)
  return(p)
}
```

When I'm using that function by calling `plotMetricsLine(df, "Income")` - it is giving an empty plot as in the picture below. What is going on wrong here ?

[image]

Comment: In your own function, add `group = Company` in `aes()`. That will work for you.

Comment: I think [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082601/ggplot2-line-chart-gives-geom-path-each-group-consist-of-only-one-observation) is almost same to yours. If you want, have a look.

Comment: Note that this happens because your x-variable is a factor, and `ggplot` assumes it should set the group accordingly.

Comment: @Axeman Thanks for the clarification. I notice that for `geom_bar` the plot is fine without  setting up `group` - what is the difference for that ?

Comment: Because the bars aren't being connected.

Comment: I got here for some reason. It might be that you have a `character/factor`. Convert it to numeric as follows `as.character(as.numeric(variable))`.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set `group` in `aes`, not just color. This function works:

```
plotMetricsLine <- function(df, metrics) {
  df <- df%>%filter(Parameter %in% metrics)
  p <-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Qtr, y=Value,group = as.factor(Company),colour=Company)) +
    geom_line(size=1)
  return(p)
}
plotMetricsLine(df, "Income")
```

note the `colour` so it has different color depending on the factor