# Error : geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

Getting error on executing code

```
scorecardData  <- data.frame(
   Date = 
c("05/10/2019","06/10/2019","07/10/2019","08/10/2019","09/10/2019"),
   Incoming.Calls= c(10,20,15,5,7)) 


ggplot(data = scorecardData, aes(x = factor(Date), y = Incoming.Calls)) +
  geom_line()
```

Getting error message :
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust
the group aesthetic?

Comment: It plots without errors when you use `aes(x = Date, y = Incoming.Calls, group = 1)` inside the ggplot call. Not sure why the error occurs though.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `group = 1`
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082601/ggplot2-line-chart-gives-geom-path-each-group-consist-of-only-one-observation)

```
scorecardData  <- data.frame(
    Date = 
        c("05/10/2019","06/10/2019","07/10/2019","08/10/2019","09/10/2019"),
    Incoming.Calls= c(10,20,15,5,7)) 


ggplot(data = scorecardData, aes(x = Date, y = Incoming.Calls, group = 1)) +
    geom_line()
```