# Data frame and reactivity in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to modify the [stockVis app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/) in the shiny tutorial series to plot data using ggplot. The original app also has xts data with daily open, high, low, close (OHLC) data. I am only trying to plot closing value vs Date. I get the following error in my code, "Warning: Error in : `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class reactiveExpr/reactive"

Edit: After [Brian's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3330437/brian) comment, I edited my call in the ggplot part of the code, but now I am getting the following error message, "Warning: Error in subset.default: argument "subset" is missing, with no default"

Here is my code

```
#Load libraries
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)

#source helper files
#source("helpers.R")


# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("stockVis", "Test Window Title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Input a stock symbol.
               Data will be collected from Yahoo Finance."),
      textInput("symb","Symbol", "SPY"),
      dateRangeInput("dates","Date Range", start="2017-01-01", end=Sys.Date()),
      br(),
      checkboxInput("log","Plot Y-axis on log scale", value = FALSE ),
      checkboxInput("adjust", "Adjust for inflation", value = FALSE),

    ),
    mainPanel(
      "Main Panel",
      plotOutput("plot")
      )
  )

)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  dataInput <- reactive({
    getSymbols(
      Symbols= input$symb, 
      src="yahoo", 
      from = input$dates[1], 
      to = input$dates[2],
      auto.assign = FALSE
    )
  })

  badf <- reactive(data.frame(dataInput)) #change xts data to date frame
  baclosedf <- reactive(subset(badf(), select=c(input$symb.Close))) #subset only closing value

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    p1 <- ggplot(
      data=baclosedf, 
      mapping=aes(x=index(baclosedf), y=baclosedf.Close))+geom_line()+geom_point()
    print(p1)
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Edit1:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({

    p1 <- ggplot(
      data=baclosedf(), 
      mapping=aes(x=index(baclosedf()), y=baclosedf.Close()))+geom_line()+geom_point()
    print(p1)
  })
```

Comment: Try with `fortify.zoo(dataInput())`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry, I dont understand which part of the code you wanted me to try that with...

Comment: I get an error in your `ui`. please correct the error to test it

Comment: UI should be fine, i rechecked the pasted code but removed the plot part below and the UI loaded.  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    p1 <- ggplot(
      data=baclosedf, 
      mapping=aes(x=index(baclosedf), y=baclosedf.Close))+geom_line()+geom_point()
    print(p1)
  })

Comment: For me, I get a bracket missing and it is not working when I added the bracket

Comment: I get `Error in tag("form", list(...)) : argument is missing, with no default`

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/    that is the original code and I am only modifying the plotting part. Maybe something got truncated while copy pasting?

Comment: Reactives are special function calls. After you define it with `foo<-reactive(...)`, you need to evaluate it in your later code, with `foo()`. So in your ggplot call, it should be `baclosedf()` etc, instead of the bare name.

Comment: @Brian thank you for writing. I did that and it seemed to have worked. However, I get a new error now. "Error in subset.default: argument "subset" is missing, with no default"

Comment: You need to fix your `subset` call to `subset(badf(), ...)` as well.

Comment: @Brian- I did that, now I am getting "Warning: Error in as.data.frame.default: cannot coerce class ‘c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")’ to a data.frame"

Answer (score 1):

There are several small but important problems in your code:

- there is `()` missing  when you transform `dataInput` as a dataframe
- the expression you use in `subset` is not good. It should be `c(paste0(input$symb, ".Close"))` instead of `c(input$symb.Close)`
- this should also be the expression to use when you select this column in the `ggplot` function: `baclosedf()[, paste0(input$symb, ".Close")]` instead of `baclosedf.Close()` (which does not refer to anything).

If you correct this, you can have a graph, but I suppose you want the x-axis to show the date. That is another problem since the function `index` will not show the dates but just a sequence of numbers: `[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20 [21]  21  22` etc.

Therefore, you need to transform the rownames (which are the dates) as a specific column. This can be made with the `rownames_to_column` function in the package `tibble`. Then, you just have to select this new column as your x-axis in `ggplot`. I added a line to rotate the labels of this axis but it is still unreadable and I suppose it is due to the fact there are more than thee years of data. Reduce the last date and you will see the labels.

Here's the full code:

```
#Load libraries
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

#source helper files
#source("helpers.R")


# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("stockVis", "Test Window Title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Input a stock symbol.
               Data will be collected from Yahoo Finance."),
      textInput("symb","Symbol", "SPY"),
      dateRangeInput("dates","Date Range", start="2017-01-01", end=Sys.Date()),
      br(),
      checkboxInput("log","Plot Y-axis on log scale", value = FALSE ),
      checkboxInput("adjust", "Adjust for inflation", value = FALSE),

    ),
    mainPanel(
      "Main Panel",
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )

)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  dataInput <- reactive({
    getSymbols(
      Symbols= input$symb, 
      src="yahoo", 
      from = input$dates[1], 
      to = input$dates[2],
      auto.assign = FALSE
    )
  })

  badf <- reactive(data.frame(dataInput())) #change xts data to date frame
  baclosedf <- reactive({
    x <- subset(badf(), select=c(paste0(input$symb, ".Close")))
    x <- rownames_to_column(x, "Date")
    }) #subset only closing value

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

   ggplot(
      data=baclosedf(), 
      mapping=aes(x=baclosedf()$Date, y=baclosedf()[, paste0(input$symb, ".Close")], group = 1)) +
      geom_line()+
      geom_point() + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit:** Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082601/ggplot2-line-chart-gives-geom-path-each-group-consist-of-only-one-observation), I added `, group = 1` in `ggplot` to plot the lines.