# Line is not added in ggplot after adding geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add lines to a very simple plot but it does not work. Why does this happen. I want to unite the points via those lines.

```
month<-c("Jan","Feb")
EA<-c(52.986,52.086)
df<-data.frame(month,EA)

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=month, y=EA)) + geom_point()+geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have to add `group = 1` to your aesthetics:

```r
library(ggplot2)
month <- c("Jan", "Feb")
EA <- c(52.986, 52.086)
df <- data.frame(month = factor(month, unique(month)), EA)

ggplot(df, aes(x = month, y = EA, group = 1)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

see: [ggplot2 line chart gives "geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082601/ggplot2-line-chart-gives-geom-path-each-group-consist-of-only-one-observation)