# What to do if my secondary line graph doesn't appear in the plot in geom_line in R

Tags: r, plot, graph, line

I want to plot a bar graph together with a line graph (secondary axis). The observation values for the line graph appears but the line doesnt appear as shown in diagram. I think maybe my transformation is wrong? Below are my code.
[image]

```
Year <- c( "2017", "2018","2019","2020")
Response <- c(6, 10, 6, 2)
Rate <- c(0.22, 0.36, 0.21, 0.07)

df <- data.frame(month, Response,Rate)

#Chart
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y=Response),stat="identity", fill="yellow",colour="sienna3")+
  geom_text(aes(label=Response, x=Year, y=1.09*Response),colour="black")+
  geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=Rate*20),colour="black",stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label=Rate, x=Year, y=Rate*25), colour="black")+
  scale_y_continuous("# Cases") +
  xlab("Month") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 13)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 14)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./25, name="Incidence rate/100000"))
```

Comment: Just add `group = 1` inside the `geom_line()` like this : `geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=Rate*20),colour="black",stat="identity",group = 1)` which is explained  in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082601/ggplot2-line-chart-gives-geom-path-each-group-consist-of-only-one-observation) question.

Comment: Just another issue with your code, you used `scale_y_continuous` twice. The first one is replaced by the second. If you want to keep the first as well, you may need remove the first and change the second to : `scale_y_continuous(name = "# Cases", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./25, name="Incidence rate/100000"))`

Comment: Your example is a bit messy. You created a variable called Year but then in the Data Frame you wrote month. In the ggplot you used Year but you called the xlab Month.

Comment: The reason why `geom_line` needs to be provided with `group = 1` is because you wrote Year as character variable. It should be a numeric variable. Remove the " " around the numbers and it will work without `group = 1`. Instead of `scale_y_continuous("# Cases") ` probably you meant `ylab("# Cases")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to clean up a bit your code to solve your problem and give you out a couple of ideas on how to improve your code.

```
Year <- c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020)
Response <- c(6, 10, 6, 2)
Rate <- c(0.22, 0.36, 0.21, 0.07)

df <- data.frame(Year, Response, Rate)

library(ggplot2)

correction <- 20

ggplot(df, aes(x = Year))  + 
  geom_bar (aes(y = Response), 
            stat = "identity", fill = "yellow", colour = "sienna3", alpha = 0.6)+
  geom_text(aes(y = Response, label = Response), 
            colour = "black", vjust = -0.5)+
  geom_line(aes(y = Rate * correction),
            colour = "black", size = 1)+
  geom_text(aes(y = Rate * correction, label = Rate * correction),
            colour = "black", vjust = -1)+
  ylab("# Cases") +
  xlab("Year") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 13)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 14)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./correction, 
                                         name = "Incidence rate/100'000")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Notice:

- `Year` is now numerical
- I cleaned up the mess with `Month` and `Year`
- I gave you a new idea on how to deal with the positioning of the numbers: `vjust`
- I added the `alpha` parameter to ease up to my eyes that strong yellow :-)
- I removed `stat = "identity"` from `geom_line`
- I created a variable called `correction` to have that correction factor of yours always equal among all the transformations
- I added a `theme` to make it look a bit more clean

You should add a title. Use `ggtitle`

Comment: this solves my problem. thank you for the succinct explanation. It looks more organized now and I can understand it easier.