# how to mutate a column of a csv file

Tags: r, ggplot2

Starting from a csv file, i'm having problem to create a lineplot with the ggplot2 library.

the error is "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

i'm tryng with the mutate function to get a line on the graph, but the variable Date is character and i need it to be numerical.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
dataset_room <- read.csv("dataset_room-temperature.csv")

ggplot (dataset_room, aes(x=Date, y=FrontLeft))+
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 line chart gives "geom\_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082601/ggplot2-line-chart-gives-geom-path-each-group-consist-of-only-one-observation)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in order to show `geom_line`: add `group=1` to your `aes`

```
ggplot (dataset_room, aes(x=Date, y=FrontLeft, group=1))+
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_line()
```