# summarized attendance by week in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an attendance record with a date column (weekly) and an attendance column for that week.

I just want a bar chart or line graph to show the change over time.

```
week <- c("09-01-20","09-07-20", "09-21-20")
att <- c(80, 140, 500)
df <- as.data.frame(week,att)
```

I have tried the following code, but the chart comes up empty or with uniform bars across all dates. A bit confused as I've replicated this from some seemingly straight forward tutorials.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=week,y="att")) +
  geom_line()

ggplot(df, aes(x=week,y=att)) +
 geom_line(fill = "identity")

 ggplot(df, aes(x=week,y=att)) +
      geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a column chart, like this

```
df <- data.frame(week = c("09-01-20","09-07-20", "09-21-20"),
                 att = c(80, 140, 500))

ggplot(df, aes(x=week, y=att)) +
      geom_col()
```

Specific to the `geom_line`, you probably saw the error message:

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

To do that, add a group=1 dummy variable, which tells the line, that all the weeks (which are currently `strings`, consider turning into dates with `as.date()`) are grouped together. As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29019102/10276092

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=week,y=att, group=1)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would consider defining the weeks with the `as.Date()` function, that will help ggplot2 creating the x axis.

```
week <- as.Date(c("09-01-20","09-07-20", "09-21-20"), format = "%m-%d-%y")
att <- c(80, 140, 500)
df <- data.frame(week,att) # as.data.frame() shouldn't work here

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=week,y=att)) +
  geom_col() # same as geom_bar(stat = "identity") but less typing
```

[image: A bar plot]

Answer (score 0):

In the OP's [`geom_bar`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.3/topics/geom_bar), specify `stat = 'identity'`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=week,y=att)) +
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

-output

[image]