# How to connect lines when x are strings?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
x=letters[1:3]
y=1:3
qplot(x, y)
qplot(x, y, geom=c('point', 'line'))
```

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust
> the group aesthetic?

I want to connect lines between the points. But when the x is a string, the above commands won't work. It works when the x is numeric. I'd think qplot should be made more user-friendly in this case.

How to make it connect the points with lines when x is a string?

Comment: Try with `qplot(x, y, group = 1, geom=c('point', 'line'))`. See [ggplot2 line chart gives "geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29019102/12993861)

Comment: Where the group option is documented in qplot. I don't find it in `?qplot`.

Comment: I think you should add group=1 as the best answer here instead of closing this question. The link that you provided is full of junk answers.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is provided by @stefan. Another one could be the following.

Sample data:

```
x=letters[1:3]
y=1:3
```

Sample code:

```
    d <- data.frame(x, y) %>%
      mutate(x = x %>% 
       factor(levels = x))

library(ggplot2)

    ggplot(data = d, aes(x = x, y = y, group = 1)) +
      geom_line() +
      scale_x_discrete(labels = x, breaks = x)
```

Plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think this is a good answer. It is too verbose.