# ggplot group aesthetic warning

Tags: r, ggplot2

I produce this simple table with R code below:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  report_year bank_financial amount
  <fct>       <chr>           <dbl>
1 2013        NPL %          0.0266
2 2014        NPL %          0.0224
3 2015        NPL %          0.0176
4 2016        NPL %          0.0164
5 2017        NPL %          0.0120
6 2018        NPL %          0.0113
7 2019        NPL %          0.0101
8 2020        NPL %          0.0137
9 2021        NPL %          0.0118

convetional_npl <- df %>% filter((bank_financial == 'Total Impaired Loan' | bank_financial == 'Gross Loan'), category == 'Universal Commercial Banks') %>%
  group_by(report_year, bank_financial) %>% summarise(amount = sum(amount), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = bank_financial, values_from = amount) %>%
  mutate(report_year = as_factor(report_year),
         `NPL %` = `Total Impaired Loan` / `Gross Loan`) %>%
  pivot_longer(!report_year, names_to = 'bank_financial', values_to = 'amount') %>%
  filter(bank_financial == 'NPL %')
```

Try to create a line chart with

```
convetional_npl %>% ggplot(aes(report_year, bank_financial)) + geom_line()
```

R studio prompted me with warning message below

```
`geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

The code produce this chart
[image]

Hope someone can advise me on this warning message and produce the complete chart.

Comment: Your `report_year` is factor, may be convert to numeric i.e. `convetional_npl %>% mutate(report_year = as.numeric(as.character(report_year))) %>% ggplot(aes(report_year, amount)) + geom_line()`

Comment: Have you tried with `group = 1` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082601/ggplot2-line-chart-gives-geom-path-each-group-consist-of-only-one-observation

Comment: Also, the second column bank_financial is character.  You may want the `amount` column as `y`?

Comment: @akrun convert report_year to numeric type works and thanks for pointing out my silly mistake for the y = bank_financial. Mind to explain why report_year in factor type gives that warning numeric type doesn't??

Comment: @RonakShah TQ so much. It works. I see the explanation in Cookbook for R about group = 1. Wonder about the meaning 1 ==> is it 1st column, 1 column??

Comment: The "1" has no special meaning. Using `group=1` means to treat all observations as belonging to one group which we name `1`. You could have also used `group=2` or `group="one"` or ...