# geom_line each group consists of one observation

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I try to make the following plot, I get the error `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation and only the points are plotted and colored.

I just want to be able to plot and control the color of each line. For what it's worth, I tried looking at the suggestions in this ([ggplot2 line chart gives "geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082601/ggplot2-line-chart-gives-geom-path-each-group-consist-of-only-one-observation?rq=2)) to no avail.

Code

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = decade, y = quantity, color = friend)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(FriendA = "green",
                                FriendB = "blue",
                                FriendC = "red")) +
  facet_wrap(~season) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Data

```
data <- structure(list(season = c("spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", 
"spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", 
"spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "winter", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer"), 
    decade = c("1980s", "1990s", "2000s", "2010s", "2020s", "1980s", 
    "1990s", "2000s", "2010s", "2020s", "1980s", "1990s", "2000s", 
    "2010s", "2020s", "1980s", "1990s", "2000s", "2010s", "2020s", 
    "1980s", "1990s", "2000s", "2010s", "2020s", "1980s", "1990s", 
    "2000s", "2010s", "2020s", "1980s", "1990s", "2000s", "2010s", 
    "2020s", "1980s", "1990s", "2000s", "2010s", "2020s", "1980s", 
    "1990s", "2000s", "2010s", "2020s"), friend = c("FriendA", 
    "FriendA", "FriendA", "FriendA", "FriendA", "FriendB", "FriendB", 
    "FriendB", "FriendB", "FriendB", "FriendC", "FriendC", "FriendC", 
    "FriendC", "FriendC", "FriendA", "FriendA", "FriendA", "FriendA", 
    "FriendA", "FriendB", "FriendB", "FriendB", "FriendB", "FriendB", 
    "FriendC", "FriendC", "FriendC", "FriendC", "FriendC", "FriendA", 
    "FriendA", "FriendA", "FriendA", "FriendA", "FriendB", "FriendB", 
    "FriendB", "FriendB", "FriendB", "FriendC", "FriendC", "FriendC", 
    "FriendC", "FriendC"), quantity = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 16, 
    25, 26, 13, 3, 11, 17, 19, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 10, 
    7, 3, 7, 7, 21, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 11, 24, 28, 19, 0, 6, 
    15, 8, 7)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-45L))
```

Comment: Try adding `group = friend` to your `aes()`, i.e. `ggplot(data, aes(x = decade, y = quantity, color = friend, group = friend)) +`